# Generate XML having repeated tags from JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml, xml-builder

I am using **xmlBuilder** library in **Nodejs** to create XML from prepared corresponding JSON.

I am creating JSON structure first and then convert it to XML. Javascript is the coding language.

It is required to create following XML structure.

```
<A>TestA</A>
<B>TestB</B>
<C>TestC1</C>
<C>TestC2</C>
<D>TestD</D>
```

Because of the repeated tags (tag C), I am unable to do it. Kindly suggest solutions!

```
{
    A: TestA,
    B: TestB,
    C: // unclear here
    D: TestD
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to do this in xmlbuilder but if you're prepared to consider other tools then I could show you how to do it in Saxon-JS.

Comment: @MichaelKay If Saxon-JS coverts Json to XML.. then I can use that too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3.0 (for example with Saxon-JS) you could transform this JSON:

```
{
    "A": "TestA",
    "B": "TestB",
    "C": ["TestC1", "TestC2"]
    "D": "TestD"
}
```

to this XML:

```
<doc>
  <A>TestA</A>
  <B>TestA</B>
  <C>TestA</C>
  <C>TestA</C>
  <D>TestA</D>
</doc>
```

with the logic:

```
<xsl:transform 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions.map"
   version="3.0" 
   expand-text="yes">
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <doc>
    <xsl:variable name="json" select="parse-json('my-input.json')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="sort(map:keys($json))">
      <xsl:element name="{.}">{$json(.)}</xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </doc>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It's a little more work to transform between JSON and XML using XSLT 3.0 than with some conversion libraries, but the advantage is it gives you total control over the output.